# Conditionals in cmd scripts

Tags: command-line-interface, appcmd, conditional

I'm doing scripting using `appcmd`. What I'd like to do is check to see if a given site exists and if does perform an action. In this case, delete it.

```
appcmd list app | find "mySite"
```

So, if the find "mySite" returns any text, I'd like to execute a delete statement. Now, I understand I could attempt to delete the site and ignore the error but that gives a (potentially) confusing output.

I've tried something like the following, where I assume I'd just use the variable `appExists` in an if statement, but it just ends up blank. Alayways.

```
set appExists=appcmd list app | find "mySite"
echo %~n0: %appExists%
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('appcmd list app ^| find "mySite"') do (
    set appExists=%%f
)
echo %~n0: %appExists%
```

But then you could skip setting an environment variable and adding an if test, and build the removal into the for loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('appcmd list app ^| find "mySite"') do (
    rem appcmd whatever whatever remove %%f here
)
```

(And check the for options (`for /?`) to use the `delims=` and `tokens=` to get whichever part of the line you need directly).

Comment: That is quite complex for what I perceive to be a simple statement.  That said, I'll give this a try to see if it achieves what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, batch files aren't very flexible. There's plenty of questions and pages on it which lead back to two answers - write the output to a file and read it in, or use a `for` loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/batch-files-how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable And linked others. Would be a more readable command in PowerShell, `Get-Website |? Name -match "mysite" | Remove-Website ` or similar.